# Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function with CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am getting the error "Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function" on the following SQL. From what I see is it something to do with the CHARINDEX function. This is on SQL Server 2014. How can this be fixed?

```
SELECT D.PAYER_TIN, '001', 13679089, YEAR( (CONVERT(CHAR(20),A.PYMNT_DT,121))), 
D.PAYEE_TIN, A.VENDOR_ID, D.PAYEE_NAME1, D.PAYEE_NAME2,  D.PAYEE_ADDRESS1, 
LEFT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP,CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-1), 
SUBSTRING(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)+2, 2), 
RIGHT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-7), 
D.WTHD_BOX1, D.WTHD_BOX2, D.WTHD_BOX7, D.WTHD_BOX18, 0.00 
FROM PS_WTHD_TRXN_TBL A, PS_TMP_1099_COPYB D, PS_TMP_1099_PA_VW2 E 
WHERE ( A.WTHD_TYPE = D.WTHD_TYPE 
     AND A.VENDOR_ID = D.VENDOR_ID 
     AND YEAR( A.PYMNT_DT) = '2018' 
     AND A.WTHD_CLASS IN ('01','02','07') 
     AND A.VENDOR_ID = E.VENDOR_ID 
     AND A.VNDR_LOC = E.VNDR_LOC 
     AND E.YEAR = '2018' 
     AND D.WTHD_CNTL_ID = 'WEST1' 
     AND D.WTHD_BOX18 > 0.00) 
  GROUP BY  D.PAYER_TIN,  YEAR( (CONVERT(CHAR(20),A.PYMNT_DT,121))),  D.PAYEE_TIN,  A.VENDOR_ID,
   D.PAYEE_NAME1,  D.PAYEE_NAME2,   D.PAYEE_ADDRESS1,  LEFT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP,
   CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-1),  SUBSTRING(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, 
   CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)+2, 2),  RIGHT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-7),
    D.WTHD_BOX1,  D.WTHD_BOX2,  D.WTHD_BOX7,  D.WTHD_BOX18
```

**EDIT:**

Added the following case statement (to the SELECT and GROUP BY) which seems to handle the condition. Turns out there was one row where this column has just a comma (",") (bad user/data input) for it's value so subtracting 7 from 1 would result in a negative number, causing the error.

```
CASE WHEN PAYEE_CITYSTZIP <> ',' THEN
RIGHT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-7)
ELSE RIGHT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)+1) END AS ZIP
```

Comment: Please isolate the problem to a single column and as few tables as possible.  Along the way, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Gordon - I have isolated it to column `RIGHT(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP, LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-7)`

Comment: I was able to fix the issue but using a Case statement, I have edited the post in case it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd argument of `RIGHT`, from: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

> If integer_expression is negative, an error is returned.

The error you get means probably that this:

```
LEN(PAYEE_CITYSTZIP) - CHARINDEX(',', PAYEE_CITYSTZIP)-7
```

returns a negative value.